# Wordpress - using plugins in ajax action

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

**Context**
I'm trying to create a custom "export to logistics" button in the WooCommerce Admin interface, specifically in the Orders table.

1. When clicked, the button displays a menu (in a pop-up) with some additional options in a tiny form.
2. When submitted, the form should trigger the inputted form data, along with some order information (such as shipping address) to be sent to the logistics company.

I can display the button and pop-up all fine, and can make the ajax call successfully as well.

**Problem**
The problem lies in the *fetching* of additional information from the WooCommerce order when in the AJAX action. For some reason, I can't seem to call WooCommerce-specific functions in this AJAX action. I'm guessing it's not properly loaded in, but can't figure out how to this gracefully. The WooCommerce function `wc_get_order($order_id)` *should* return a WC_Order object (as it does in the popup generation), but instead only returns false.

Here's the form code, nothing special really:

```
// POPOVER HTML/CSS
<form action="<?php echo wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=vanlent_submit_export&order_id=' . $order->id ), 'send_to_vanlentlogistics' ); ?>" method="post">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="extra_groot_formaat" value="extragrootformaat"> Extra groot formaat</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="handtekening" value="handtekening"> Handtekening voor ontvangst</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="brievenbuspakje" value="brievenbuspakje"> Brievenbuspakje</label><br>
    <input style="margin-top:15px;" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Exporteren', 'vanlent'); ?>" class="button button-primary action">
</form>
```

Here's the (start of) the export function, inside the ajax action.

```
// EXPORT
add_action( 'wp_ajax_vanlent_submit_export', 'vanlent_submit_export' );
function vanlent_submit_export() {
    $nonce = $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'];
    $order_id = $_REQUEST['order_id'];

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'send_to_vanlentlogistics' ) ) {
        wp_die( 'Not allowed' );
    } else {
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $order->update_status('processing', 'order_note');
        var_dump($order); // Try echo'ing it for now
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? If not, I'm suspecting that the problem has to do with `$order_id` not being properly passed in to `wc_get_order`.  What do you get when you `var_dump($order_id);`?